# Allocate /Deallocate a resource

Tags: c

I have to manage a resource. It is basically a unique number to identify a Layer 2 connection in a switch. There can be 16k such connections and so every time a user wishes to configure a connection,he/she needs to allot a unique index. Similarly, when a user wishes to remove a connection, the resource (the number) must be released and must be available to configure(and identify) other connections. As of now i am using an bitmap based on unsigned char arrays to maintain which bit is set/unset

to monitor 16k numbers i am using an unsigned char array of 2048 bytes, wherein each bit represents a resource:

```
unsigned char bitmap_array[2048];
```

Is there a better way of doing the same, that does not involve such a huge chunk of static allocation?

Comment: any reason why not to? are you using a platform where memory is very limited? static 2k doesn't seem that bad

Comment: Do you store any other information related to a connection? Why did you decide to use a number instead of a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

another way could be using a Set [Hash/Tree], which size will be dynamically chosen. every element is in the set if and only if this resource is allocated.

the problems with these solution are:

1. it will be slower.

2. when number of elements is high, it will take more memory then the static array.

for 2k, I'd stick with the static bitmap array.

**one more possibility:**

using the same trick Virtual Memory uses [(pages)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Paged_virtual_memory).

partition your 'array' into N parts, and create an extra table of size N.

every element in the table will be mapped a part of the array it is relevant to.

now, when you allocate resource k, you will have to allocate the part of the array which k is in, [and set all the other values to 0].

it will still be slower then the chunk, and when all entrees are allocated, it will requires extra N*4 bytes.

I'd use this solution only if the data is much larger then 2k.

more info: http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this embedded?  2k isn't that much memory by desktop standards.  You could always use a hash-table, but you probably wont get the performance you are getting now.  You can also just dynamically allocate the block if it makes you feel better.

My C might be a little garbled, but if I remember it should look like this:

```
unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *) malloc(2048 * sizeof (unsigned char));
//insert null pointer check here
```

Just remember to call `free` when you are done...

Seriously, 2k of static allocation is probably fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :)